# Code optimization in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, optimization, laravel-5

I am developing once attendance system,when recording attendance,I have to do bulk insertion. I am using following code and it is working fine.

```
foreach ($request->selectedEmployees as $employee) {
        foreach ($employee['attendances'] as $att) {
            $att['created_by'] = Auth::id();
            $attendaces [] = new Attendance($att);
        }
        Employee::findOrFail($employee['id'])->attendances()
                ->saveMany($attendaces);
    }
```

My input structure,

```
[
    "selectedEmployees": [
        {
            "id": 119,
             "attendances": [
            {
                "id": "119_01",
                "employees_id": 119,
                "type": 1,
                "date": "01-07-2015",
                "signin": "9.00",
                "signout": "6.00",
                "lunch_in_time": "1.30",
                "lunch_out_time": "2.00",
                "add_in_time": "",
                "add_out_time": "",
                "note": ""
            }
           ]   
      }
]
```

I want to optimize my code,

1. avoid insert in loop and do bulk insert
2. put insertion process as back end running as thread and notify user once it is finished(I am using angularJS front end)

Is these optimization is possible in `laravel5.1` and is there any other optimization technique?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to understand, that even if you are using `saveMany()` method, Laravel saves every row separately. So your algorithm's complexity will be O(n) even if you will try to optimize it somehow. And it is not bad.
2. You can use assync ajax request. It will not block user's page and after it will be finished you will show user a notice. Or you can use [broadcasting events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#broadcasting-events) mechanism. It is more complex, but will make your code more elegant, so to say.

Comment: what about `queues` in laravel?

Comment: @MuhammedShihabuddeen broadcasting mechanism works right through the queues. That's why I said that it is more preferable, but more complex solution.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Now i have written one `job class` and working fine. now I am trying to understand broadcasting mechanism. If you don't mind,then can you please give me an idea about difference of  `queues`,`job` and `broadcasting mechanism`

Comment: @MuhammedShihabuddeen job is a peace of code that you want to do in the background. To do so you have to push it to the queue. Queue is a background process that from time to time watches if there any job to do and if it sees a new one, it fires it. Broadcasting works the same way, but the only difference is that it can send you a result of the task in assync way via websockets. It works the same way as events. You subscribe for the event, and when it fires, you get a message. You can see the full info here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events

Comment: @MuhammedShihabuddeen excuse me for the confusing explanation, it's kind a hard to explain events/queues/broadcasting in one short comment ))

Comment: even small explanation given me short idea. Anyhow am not trying `broadcasting` because i have to lean web socket as well :( . I did it using job and it became faster.

Comment: @MuhammedShihabuddeen websockets are not the only way. Result can be sent via ajax or pusher too.

Comment: where can I find failed jobs and successful jobs for notification to user later?

Comment: @MuhammedShihabuddeen successful jobs can notify by any mechanism you choose. Failed jobs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs